# footnotes at the end of the book

Tags: footnotes

Is it possible to have all footnotes placed at one specific place in my document instead of bottom of each page? I have multiple footnotes scattered in the article and it would be clearer if all of them are at the very end of the article

**Edit (moved from an ``answer'')**

is it possible in endnotes to have links in each number where I placed footnote to the actual footnote at the end?

Comment: take a look at the `endnotes` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Besides `endnotes`, there's the more recent and more customizable `enotez`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starting point:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enotez} % for endnotes
\usepackage{hyperref} % for hyperlinks

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}

This has an endnote.\endnote{The text of the note}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Clicking on the footnote number will bring to the endnotes page.